# Taking backup of a file in remote location using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy  a file (example: /home/abc.jar) from controller machine(source system)  to remote server. but before copying that file, I want to take the backup of the already existed file (/home/abc.jar) on the remote server to some directory (example /home/bck/abc.jar). then copy the new file ,

How can I write the playbook for this using ansible?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

The docs are your friend:

[Ansible Copy Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html)

[Ansible Template Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html)

Both contain a 'backup' parameter which will automatically take a backup of a file prior to making changes.

Comment: The search engine on their documentation isn't really good. I can't search for it.